# How to open published app from Play Store?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-install-apk

Published app is visible on Play Store , after installing there's no Open option on Play Store(only uninstall button shows) and also I cannot find it on home screen

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? I have the same. Please, help